Event driven system design
I recently started learning about event-driven systems, and I would be interested in implementing real-time analytics with them (I just want to provide some dashboards for now)
Let's say I have the following tables in Postgres (very simplified):

customers: id, is_alias
transactions: id, price, customer_id, product_id
products: id, name, brand_name

For analytics, I need to join all of these tables together, as well as apply some additional filtering and grouping logic on top.
I've seen there are 2 main ways to implement this with events:

Make the backend send already denormalized events to a single Kafka topic
Make the backend send different events for each of the tables to different topics, join them with stream processing app (i.e. Flink)

1. Make the backend send already denormalized events to a single Kafka topic
I can make my backend send an event with data of all 3 tables, since at the moment the transaction is created I have data from all the tables available in the backend:
key: transaction_id, values: customer_is_alias, price, product_name, product_brand

The issue with this approach is how to handle updates. If a product_name is updated, I need to find all the transactions associated with that product and send an event for each of them with the new data. This could be feasible, but the biggest problem is that it would not only be querying for transactions, I would have to query for subscribers too in order to send the full event.
Question 1: How is this issue resolved in real-world apps? Do they just send a "partial" update event, for example (without customer field):
key: transaction_id, values: price, product_name, product_brand

and then have logic somewhere to add this partial updates to the main initial event? Are there any examples / best practices about of how to implement this type of logic anywhere (using different topics, how would the queries look like etc)
2. Make the backend send different events for each of the tables to different topics, join them with stream processing app
I can just send the different events for each table (transactions, customers, products) to different topics, and then use Flink to join the streams and create any required dynamic tables and different views to store my analytics data. But this means the stream processing will have to be doing joins between the events in 3 streams all the time, which seems it would be more expensive than the option above.
Question 2: In summary, can anyone advice me about which of these two options is better in general or more widely adopted? I think I've seen more frequently the second, but would like to understand if it is the right way to go.
Last, it is hard to wrap my head around how deletes work in this world of immutable events. Going back to the event:
key: transaction_id, values: customer_is_alias, price, product_name, product_brand

If a transaction is deleted in my relational DB, which type of event I'd have to emit and which type of query would I use so that it gets dropped from the final analytics results?
Thanks a ton in advance! :)
